# Does the angle of two vectors stay the same if they are arranged head to head?

Tags: vectors

I was wondering, if you know the angle of two vectors when they are arranged tail to tail, for example both have their tails at the origin point. Will that angle be the same as the angle if they were both arranged with their *heads* at the origin point?

EDIT:

Here's an illustration of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are opposite angles of a parallelogram.